# Telegram bot API: get message id to forward it

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

So, I need my bot to forward a message of a chat. But in order to do so, I need to get the id of the message I want to forward (it's an old message). How can I get the id of that message so I can send it?

This is the code I'm using

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def reply_ids(message):
    cid = message.chat.id
    bot.reply_to(message, "The message id is: " + str(message.message_id) + " This chat ID is: " + str(cid))
```

Comment: How did you get the message you are trying to forward? (what is it's source?)

Comment: @DeanFenster  It's from a group I'm in

Comment: Throught what API? I'm having a hard time understanding how come you don't get the message id with the actual message...

Comment: @DeanFenster I'm using https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: you've tagged this question wrong. python-telegram-bot refers to another api

Answer (score 2):

When receiving a message, the id will be in `message.message_id`, as documented [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message).

Comment: The thing is, it's the message id from what looks like the bot conversation. It's difficult to explain. But you can take a look, try talking with my bot: @jmml_test_bot It will give the message ID of your message and the ID of the chat. One would expect the message ID to be 1 (or 0) if it's the first message in the conversation. However, it will be a bigger number, other numbers are older messages that bot has received.

Comment: Then, trying to get the ID of a message in a group chat will do the same, it won't show me the correct ID...

Comment: Why would the ID be 0 or 1? Telegram stores all messages on it's servers and should have a unique id for each and every one of them.

Comment: Oh, so it should be a bigger like random number. Well, try talking to my bot. It will not give you that.

Comment: So it seems to be a running index per chat. But why does that make it invalid?

Comment: Because it's not per chat. Try talking to it with another account or adding it to a group... It will give the next number for each message... What number did you get?

Comment: 453-465. Let the message_id picking algorithm remain a mystery. Have you tried forwarding a message?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't output the same ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93878/discussion-between-dean-fenster-and-jose-maria).

Answer (score 2):

If it is a supergroup or a channel, you can get the message_id by clicking on the message (in telegram web ) then choosing copy message link. the link will be in this form "https://t.me/channel_name/message_id"

**This solution is to find the message_id manually!!**

Comment: Looks like you're giving an answer on how to get a message ID manually (clicking through the UI) but the question is about getting the ID programmatically via the API.

Comment: yes, my bad!!!
I was searching for the method to find the id manually, in my search I found this question. After I found the solution I liked to share it

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been working with callback queries from inline buttons. One things I noticed is that in order to reply to the exact message that had the buttons Telegram needs to know both message.chat_id and message.message_id. You can try with both. This is more a comment then an answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Now, It's `update.message.message_id`

Answer (score 0):

Using `python`, if you have a `CommandHandler()` you can read the `chat_id` and `message_id` like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72433953/1000741