# Telegram Bot How to delete or remove a message or media from a channel or group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to know an example of removing message or file like a photo

I did not find any functional tutorial in this regard,

Comment: Now it's available to do!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Telegram Bot API right now.

UPD 2017-05-19: There is an official method ***deleteMessage***, more info:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43965602/1140438

Comment: There is method for deleting messages not with bot API: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteMessages

Comment: Thanks @ihoru, does that mean the bot can't delete a for example incorrect post?
Are you sure about that?

Comment: is there any solution in this regard?

Comment: it is not even possible other administrators to delete the message from the channel
is there any solution?

Comment: Channel's administrator can delete message posted by bot to the channel, but not from private chat with user.

Comment: With telegram bot api v2.1 can we do this or it is still un available?

Comment: @MohammadRezaEsmaeilzadeh It's still unavailable.

Comment: @ihoru I couldn't delete the replyed and forwarded messages with this method! but deleting usual messages are totally ok, can you help me bro!?

Comment: @Ali give us more information. What error do you get?

Comment: @ihoru thanks bro, the error was gone! but I didn't understand what was the problem! :))

Answer (score 33):

There is an official support of ***deleteMessage*** method in Bot API 3.0. More details here:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

> https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/deleteMessage?chat_id=CID&message_id=MID

As you can see there are two arguments: `chat_id` and `message_id`.

You can remove bot's messages or other messages (if bot is admin) except service messages (such as join/leave messages).

1. On success, it will return following JSON object:
   `{"ok":true,"result":true}`.
2. If you are trying to remove service message or other user's message, but bot is not an admin:
   `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message can't be deleted"}`.
3. If you are trying to remove non-existent message or its already deleted:
   `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message to delete not found"}`

Comment: Good answer. Could you give an example how to manage those three cases in javaScript

Answer (score 2):

###### Kindly check with the below code snippet!, the below code have worked for me!

```
String chatId = String.valueOf(callbackQuery.getMessage().getChatId());
Integer messageId = callbackQuery.getMessage().getMessageId();
DeleteMessage deleteMessage = new DeleteMessage(chatId, messageId);
try {
  execute(deleteMessage);
}catch(TelegramApiException tae) {
  throw new RuntimeException(tae);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can forward message and save message id, and then remove that message. if you can do it, your message exist.

do it:

```
try:
   mes=bot.forward_message(chat_id=?,from_chat_id=?,message_id=?)
   bot.delete_message(chat_id=?,message_id=mes.id)
except:
   print("your message deleted")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods in bot api that let you to edit a message: `editMessageText` and `editMessageCaption`. It is not ideal, but you can use it as an alternative.

For example by editing the message to:

> "This message is unavailable."

Answer (score 0):

Using `python`, if you have a `CommandHandler()` you can read the `chat_id` and `message_id` like so:

```
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", handler_start))

def handler_start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    message_id = update.message._id_attrs[0]
    context.bot.delete_message(chat_id, message_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If on php. I send message. Get response from it (message id of bot) And use deleteMessage

```
<?php
$botToken = "yourBotToken";
$botAPI = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$msg = $update['message']['text'];
if ($msg == '/start') {
$data = http_build_query([
        'text' => "test message (delete this)",
        'chat_id' => $update['message']['chat']['id'],
]);
$send = file_get_contents($botAPI . "/sendMessage?{$data}");

$response = json_decode($send), true); // decode response
$message_id = $response['result']['message_id']; // get bots message

// Deleting message
$data_del = http_build_query([
    'chat_id' => $update['message']['chat']['id'],
    'message_id' => $message_id,
]);
    file_get_contents($botAPI . "/deleteMessage?{$data_del}");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/deleteMessage?chat_id=CID&message_id=MID

Example
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:zzzzzzzzxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyy/deleteMessage?chat_id=123456789&message_id=123456**,**

It is important that the id of the message temine with a (comma) (,) and you can see it in the json when you send the message

Comment: Is this any different than [the existing answer by fox.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43965602/10953328)?