# Can't delete message telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a channel where the bot sends messages and today(27.03) Im trying to delete the message that the bot sent 19.03 using python wraper for telegram api. Request to api return "Bad Request: message can't be deleted"

Bot have full privileges as administrator

Thats my code

```
bot.delete_message(chat_id=query.message.chat_id, message_id=query.message.message_id)
```

[This just explain how to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269776/telegram-bot-how-to-delete-or-remove-a-message-or-media-from-a-channel-or-group)

Comment: Perhaps the message is too old to be deleted: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telegram Bot How to delete or remove a message or media from a channel or group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269776/telegram-bot-how-to-delete-or-remove-a-message-or-media-from-a-channel-or-group)

Comment: @anned20
But "If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there." or this is not exception from time restriction?

Comment: "If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete **any** message there." its from documentation of api